# How to start Google PubSub and task in asyncio python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-api, python-asyncio, google-publisher-tag

I have several tasks (async def), one of them has an eternal loop, the second has another loop that processes requests. But when trying to create a new task where Google PubSub will receive all notifications - Pub/Sub stops other tasks from running and loops how to make multiple tasks in asyncio, but so that they work independently of each other.

P.S - If you bring a basic example, this is how to run two loops, the second one will not work simultaneously with the first one (I need to solve this, but already in asyncio)

```
async def coursework_handler():
def handler(msg):
    data = json.loads(msg.data.decode("utf-8"))
    if data["eventType"] == "MODIFIED":
        print(data)

stream = subscriber.subscribe(sub_path, callback=handler)
try:
    stream.result()
except:
    stream.cancel()
    stream.result()
```

Comment: Please, add some self-contained code with your structure and what have you tried. No one will write a program from zero for you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You likely can do what you want by running the googlge pub-sub loop in  a separate thread than your async loop. 
But I can't give you any example code, since you have not done so.

Comment: I used the basic example from google.cloud pubsub_1v, yes I mean run in a separate thread, but is there a way to run pubsub using multiprocessing? To be honest, I have no desire to create threads, and practice has shown that multiprocessing is more productive.